# php file force download error

Tags: file

I am trying to force a download.  here is my code:

```
 <?PHP
 // Define the path to file
 $file = 'http://myimage.com/users/test/uploads/1234.png';

 if(!file)
 {
     // File doesn't exist, output error
     die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {
     header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
    header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
    readfile($file);
}
?>
```

here is the error that I get in firefox: "The image "file:///C:/Users/Username/Downloads/1234%20(4).png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors."
the %20(4) is a space, and probably the 4th copy i've tried downloading.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Content-Type` is wrong. All that's needed to force a download is `Content-Disposition: attachment`; change it to `image/png` instead of `application/octet-stream`.

Also, you have a space before your opening `<?php` tag. You need to take that out.

Also, your "file exists" check doesn't do what you think it does. Use [`file_exists`](http://php.net/file_exists) to check if a file exists, and remember the `$` sign.

Comment: alright.  so the file does not exist! hm... that's weird... the variable $file destination is viewable in the browser.. why wouldn't it be able to download it?

Comment: @droidus: Is the file on another server? Your firewall may be blocking it, or remote `fopen` may be disabled.

Comment: hm, it is being hosted by someone else, yes.  and how do i check if fopen is disabled?

Comment: @droidus: Go into your `php.ini` and change `allow_url_fopen` to `On`. If it's already `On`, you'll probably need to unblock outgoing connections on port 80 for PHP.

Comment: hm, not sure that they give me access to that... will have to check with them... is there anything else I can do in the mean time?

Comment: @droidus: You can always just redirect to the actual hosted image with a `Location` header, or should worst come to worst, use cURL to send a direct request.

Comment: hm, would that work since it can't even find the image?  also, what would that code look like?

Comment: @droidus: `header("Location: $file\r\n");`? As for cURL, if this doesn't work for you, I'll put that in later. It's rather tedious :)

Comment: so frustrating... i still get "file not found"

Comment: @droidus: Are you *sure* this file actually exists? :) `$file` must not be what you think it is; redirecting will always work.

Comment: is there code that I could try out that we know that works maybe?

Comment: @droidus: Try reading or redirecting to this image: `http://i.stack.imgur.com/dSNdb.png`

Comment: my code:  <?PHP
 $file = 'http://i.stack.imgur.com/dSNdb.png';
 if(!file_exists($file))
 {
     die('file not found');
 }
 else
 {
  header('Content-disposition: attachment;filename='.$file);
 header('Content-type: image/png');
 readfile($file);
 }
?> output: file not found

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9523/discussion-between-minitech-and-droidus)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you don't have any blank lines outside the `<?php` `?>` tags.